# Why won't Angular 12 run in Edge or Firefox after adjusting polyfill.ts?

Tags: angular

I have an app running in Angular 12 which shows a blank screen in Firefox and Edge, but runs in Chrome.

I have followed the instructions in polyfill.ts for

import 'classlist.js';  // Run `npm install --save classlist.js`.
import 'web-animations-js';  // Run `npm install --save web-animations-js`.

My `package.json` looks like this

```json
    {
      "name": "project-name",
      "version": "0.0.0",
      "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "start": "ng serve",
        "build": "ng build",
        "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
        "test": "ng test"
      },
      "private": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "~12.2.0",
        "@angular/cdk": "^12.2.7",
        "@angular/common": "~12.2.0",
        "@angular/compiler": "~12.2.0",
        "@angular/core": "~12.2.0",
        "@angular/flex-layout": "^12.0.0-beta.35",
        "@angular/forms": "~12.2.0",
        "@angular/material": "^12.2.7",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "~12.2.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.2.0",
        "@angular/router": "~12.2.0",
        "ajv": "^8.6.3",
        "animate.css": "^4.1.1",
        "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
        "core-js": "^2.6.12",
        "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
        "material-icons": "^1.5.1",
        "ngx-cookie-service": "^12.0.3",
        "ngx-trim-directive": "^1.1.0",
        "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
        "tslib": "^2.3.0",
        "web-animations-js": "^2.3.2",
        "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.2.7",
        "@angular/cli": "~12.2.7",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "~12.2.0",
        "@types/jasmine": "~3.8.0",
        "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
        "jasmine-core": "~3.8.0",
        "karma": "~6.3.0",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
        "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
        "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
        "typescript": "~4.3.5"
      }
    }
```

Here is my polyfill

```js
    /**
     * This file includes polyfills needed by Angular and is loaded before the app.
     * You can add your own extra polyfills to this file.
     *
     * This file is divided into 2 sections:
     *   1. Browser polyfills. These are applied before loading ZoneJS and are sorted by browsers.
     *   2. Application imports. Files imported after ZoneJS that should be loaded before your main
     *      file.
     *
     * The current setup is for so-called "evergreen" browsers; the last versions of browsers that
     * automatically update themselves. This includes Safari >= 10, Chrome >= 55 (including Opera),
     * Edge >= 13 on the desktop, and iOS 10 and Chrome on mobile.
     *
     * Learn more in https://angular.io/guide/browser-support
     */

    /***************************************************************************************************
     * BROWSER POLYFILLS
     */

    /**
     * IE11 requires the following for NgClass support on SVG elements
     */
    import 'classlist.js';  // Run `npm install --save classlist.js`.

    /**
     * Web Animations `@angular/platform-browser/animations`
     * Only required if AnimationBuilder is used within the application and using IE/Edge or Safari.
     * Standard animation support in Angular DOES NOT require any polyfills (as of Angular 6.0).
     */
    import 'web-animations-js';  // Run `npm install --save web-animations-js`.

    /**
     * By default, zone.js will patch all possible macroTask and DomEvents
     * user can disable parts of macroTask/DomEvents patch by setting following flags
     * because those flags need to be set before `zone.js` being loaded, and webpack
     * will put import in the top of bundle, so user need to create a separate file
     * in this directory (for example: zone-flags.ts), and put the following flags
     * into that file, and then add the following code before importing zone.js.
     * import './zone-flags';
     *
     * The flags allowed in zone-flags.ts are listed here.
     *
     * The following flags will work for all browsers.
     *
     * (window as any).__Zone_disable_requestAnimationFrame = true; // disable patch requestAnimationFrame
     * (window as any).__Zone_disable_on_property = true; // disable patch onProperty such as onclick
     * (window as any).__zone_symbol__UNPATCHED_EVENTS = ['scroll', 'mousemove']; // disable patch specified eventNames
     *
     *  in IE/Edge developer tools, the addEventListener will also be wrapped by zone.js
     *  with the following flag, it will bypass `zone.js` patch for IE/Edge
     *
     *  (window as any).__Zone_enable_cross_context_check = true;
     *
     */

    /***************************************************************************************************
     * Zone JS is required by default for Angular itself.
     */
    import 'zone.js';  // Included with Angular CLI.
```

Why won't the script run in Edge and Firefox?

Comment: Can you provide me your `polyfill.ts` file ?

Comment: @RaphaëlBalet I've added the polyfill.ts to the question

Comment: I've posted an answer, if this doesn't work I'll need the log from edge or firefox.  Maybe you'll have additional information there

Comment: Is your polyfill configured to be used? E.g. in your build configuration in `angular.json` an option added to specify which file to use.  An entry like `..."build":{...,"options":{...,"polyfills":"src/polyfills.ts",...},...},...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`polyfill.ts` isn't that required anymore, since

- Edge is now [running under chromium](https://support.microsoft.com/fr-fr/microsoft-edge/t%C3%A9l%C3%A9charger-le-nouveau-microsoft-edge-bas%C3%A9-sur-chromium-0f4a3dd7-55df-60f5-739f-00010dba52cf)
- Firefox does just well on its own.
- E11 is [finally dead](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-blog/microsoft-365-apps-say-farewell-to-internet-explorer-11-and/ba-p/1591666)

This is the only part you'll need in your `pollyfill.ts` file

```js
/***************************************************************************************************
 * Zone JS is required by default for Angular itself.
 */
import 'zone.js' // Included with Angular CLI.

/***************************************************************************************************
```

And everything should work just fine, so please do

`npm un classlist.js` & `npm un web-animations-js`

Comment: This works, thanks!

Comment: @shazzoom glead to hear, then please, do then accept it as an answer and give an up vote ;)

Comment: I clicked the accept answer, but I don't have enough rep to up vote yet

Comment: @shazzoom Then thx you, and welcome to stackoverflow ;)